# Adding looping within VideoView

Tags: android, loops, android-studio, android-videoview

I'm having a bit of trouble with a small application I've put together in Android Studio.  Essentially the application is suppose to launch - autoplay a video and keep looping until touched...

I've got everything bar the looping working - I've tried a few suggestions from here but none have worked in my case (or not had the coding skills to get them to...)

**Main code below**

```
package com.pixel.danny.screensaverhfx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.hab);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.start();
    videoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            finish();
        }
    });    }
}
```

Comment: **as you mention autoplay a video and keep looping until touched** which means you want to pause videos or what???

Comment: Sorry, no the app exits when touched - It's basically a screensaver.

Comment: remove this line `finish();` so that your app not exits.it will keep play...

Comment: I want to keep the finish() that is what makes the app exit when touched - all I want to do is add the looping so the video keeps playing until I touch it to exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what below code is doing when you are touch the `Videoview`  you are finish the activity so app will get close....

```
videoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            finish();   //remove this line 
            videoView.stopPlayback() // you can use this for stopPlay
        }
    });
```

So remove `finish();` you problem got reslove

**and if you want to looping**

```
 videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              videoView.start();   //it will start again
        }
    });
```

Comment: The code above (the looping part) flags up lots of errors in the code

Comment: @Danny ok fine.then keep finish(); method...please check my update answer..still you getting any issues let me know...with error log

Comment: Thanks for the help Gowthaman  just updated the code with what you've edited above but getting the error :

error: non-static method start() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: I've created a pastebin to show my code so far in case it's my placement etc
[link](https://pastebin.com/D3dwRQ7K)

Comment: okay so I found the answer - I declared VideoView as Final and then your code above worked! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `finish();` rather call `videoView.stopPlayback()`

Comment: I call `finish()` so that the app exits when I touch it